# How to create a path on Street View?

Tags: google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

I uploaded a bunch of images to StreetView. I also connected them, for example [here is one image](https://www.google.com/maps/@45.9470927,7.6327143,3a,75y,40.72h,90t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sAF1QipPsolOl3PklveoqQQaXmEwhsAuMlJ0aDk1pTIGZ!2e10!3e11!7i7776!8i3888). The connections seem to be working I can navigate from one image to another.

My question is why aren't they displayed as a path (continuous blue line) on the map? They are displayed as separate images (circles on the map). How should I change them to become a path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect one pano to multiple panos using Google street view publish API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44886920/how-to-connect-one-pano-to-multiple-panos-using-google-street-view-publish-api)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as he is asking about the "blue line", not just connections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have > 50 panoramas with a distance < 5m between two connected panoramas.
After some days (weeks?) Google will convert them to a blue line in a separate processing step.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it documented somewhere? The first part of the condition (> 50) is not a problem, but the other one might be, let me calculate it. I uploaded them 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I can not find my notes for the Street View Summit, but in this talk they are even talking about less the 3m https://youtu.be/EW8YKwuFGkc?t=2160

Comment: Finally I uploaded all of my images to streetview. I have 2856 connected images. A 2477 long subset of the images has less then 5m distance. (I calculated the distance in 3D, assuming the earth radius is 6371000m.) Blue line is still not there. What do you think, all of the images must have less than 5m distance? Or is it enough if this rule applies only a subset of the images?

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas... maybe someone else?